# What is the version of Unix and the name of the computer it run on in this 1982 video?

Tags: history, unix, identify-this-computer

I am learning about the history of computers, and based on what I know so far, Unix was run on a large computer, and in order to use it, you have to use a computer terminal.

Does anybody knows what is the version of Unix and the name of the (large) computer it run on in this 1982 video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc4ROCJYbm0

These are some snapshots from the video:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Computer]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: It might be helpful for context if you can tell us where in the half-hour video those snapshots were taken from.

Comment: What you'd be likely to see of a "big computer" in the 80ies would be only the terminal. And what we see in your second picture is a good old vt100 terminal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100 . The "computer" is most probably hidden in some big server room and could nearly be anything running Unix. Unfortunately, the screens you show seem to be from applications programs - Not much to deduct from that.

Comment: @tofro in the second photo I think the big computer is the set of cabinets against the wall in the background...

Comment: @StephenKitt Yep - and that could basically be anything - Although, it does look a bit VAX-alike to me

Comment: @tofro, that's a PDP-11 for sure: black and magenta control panel at 3:20 is the giveaway: [pdp-11](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pdp-11&amp;t=canonical&amp;iax=1&amp;ia=images)

Comment: @scruss I must admit I've never seen a PDP-11 with the front panels closed (or even present), although I have worked on some (mainly RSX-11M, not unix). From my memory, a PDP-11 needs to look like any other bunch of  PCBs in a backplane ;)

Comment: I'm not sure the first image is Unix at all. The format of text on screen and how the user is editing one of the fields in the video makes it look like a block mode terminal, which weren't used with Unix. It's likely a shot of production software being used by AT&T running on some sort of more traditional mainframe or minicomputer OS for the time.

Comment: Unix was much more likely to be running on a SMALL computer, typically a PDP-11 or similar. On a big computer (which people only started referring to as mainframes when smaller machines became widespread) you would be running an IBM operating system or one of its competitors (e.g. Burroughs or Univac), invariably developed and supplied by the hardware manufacturer.

Comment: The terminal in the 2nd picture looks like an HP 2640. The VT100 had a squarer screen, and the black plastic surrounding the screen extended to partially cover the top of the terminal.

Answer (score 14):

The "p" program shown is a rudimentary pager (just stopped each 22 lines to wait to hit enter - 22 was chosen because some tools formatted output into 66-line pages with headers and footers) that appears in Research Unix v8 and onward, which suggests that what was being shown was the then-current version of Research Unix (this was three years before v8 was formally released). Version numbers weren't really a thing for Research Unix outside the preparation of printed manuals and distribution tapes.

The other commands - makewords, lowercase, unique (by that name, though it may well simply be `uniq` renamed), and mismatch (which appears to be a cut-down version of `spell`) don't appear in v8 but may have been demonstration programs or scripts created to show off the concept of pipelines for the video.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing. Thanks for trying to identify the operating system despite the other answer saying that it is impossible - this certainly cuts it down.

Answer (score 11):

It is likely a PDP-11/40, judging from the front panel just visible to the left of the terminal.

The PDP-11/40 is consistent with the purple/red paint on the cabinet; and with the fact it's running some sort of UNIX. It also seems that they are using the computer to do CAD designs of microchips; I know that the ULA in the ZX Spectrum was designed in this way on a PDP-11.

I think it's impossible to say which version of UNIX is running here but it could be 1BSD or 2BSD. These were apparently popular unices on the PDP-11 around 1982.

Comment: Given the video was produced by AT&T and contains interviews with Bell Labs employees the version of Unix being used is almost certainly Research Unix. In 1982 they would either be using Version 7 or more likely some intermediate internal version between the official releases of V7 and V8.

Comment: The pattern of the toggle switches at the bottom is more consistent with those of a [PDP-11/50](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/pdp1150-console.jpg)

Comment: Or a [PDP-11/45](http://www.pdp-11.nl/pdp11-45/pdp11-45-front-47.jpg)